# Word for Unusual Number

Tags: single-word-request, numbers

Years ago I read about a German word that meant "unusual or special number." Examples were given as 12345, 9861689 (numerical palindromes), 2468, and such. I cannot find anything like this on line and am wondering if I was tricked.

Comment: *Palindromes* are simply called *das Palindrom (sg.) / die Palindrome (pl.)* in German. You could call them **Ziffernpalindrom** or **Zahlenpalindrom** if they were done with digits instead of letters. That's a valid and easy to understand German word I just made up. I bet someone already used it before.

Comment: One thing that came to my mind is "Schnapszahl".

Comment: @Javatasse i think that's it. Make it an answer.

Comment: @bukwyrm: Non of the examples posted in the question is a *Schnapszahl*. A *Schnapszahl* is a number with 2 or more digits, where all digits are equal. Examples are 55, 777, 1111. The English term is *"repdigit"*. One of Marks example is a palindrome (in German: Palindrom), the others are built from ascending digits, but I don't know any special name for this kind of numbers (neither in German nor in English).

Comment: What is an "unusual" number? What makes a numver usual? What makes it unusual?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast , a palindrome can be called a Schnapszahl, as can 69 and other numbers that could conceivably be Schnaps-induced misreadings. I concur on the issue of the ascending numbers, though. My guess was that OP was misremembering the examples, or OPs informant was operating on an expanded definition.

Comment: @bukwyrm Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schnapszahl) agrees with Hubert's definition of _Schnapszahl_ . There might be lokal deviations in usage, though.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Der Begriff *Schnapszahl* hat nicht nur regionale Unterschiede in der Bedeutung, sondern auch in der Frequenz. In Österreich wird er kaum verwendet. Ich kenne das Wort eigentlich nur aus dem deutschen Fernsehen.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're searching for the word **Zahlenmuster** which means that the numbers do have a specific regularity.

There are also some math lessons where children have to search for so called ANNA, TILL and NANA regularities. ANNA numbers would be something like 8228, 9449, TILL numbers are something like 1233, 6788 and NANA numbers are something like 6767, 4545.

**Zahlenpalindrom** would be the word for numbers like 862268 whose number system has the same value read from the front and back.